# How do I get an bluetooth id of a device that opens my site

Tags: javascript, bluetooth

I need to get a Bluetooth address of a device that is connecting to my site. Here is a couple of questions:
1. Can it be achieved with Bluetooth API only? If not, which way could I use to do what I described above?
2. About that API. Let's imagine a situation. I have a phone. Bluetooth is turned on. I'm visiting my website and I need to get BT address of my phone. Could this code work out:

```
const button = document.querySelector('#the-button');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
        filters: [{
            services: ['battery_service']
        }]
    }).then(device => {
        console.log('Got device:', device.name);
        console.log('id:', device.id);
    });
});
```

I can't understand if I have to connect my phone to another device or all I have to do is using the above code.
So, generally, there are 2 questions I want to ask:
1. Are there any other ways to get BT address of a device besides Bluetooth API?
2. How many devices do I need to use BT API?